# ERROR: audio conversion failed: Unknown encoder 'libmp3lame'

Tags: macos, youtube-dl

I'm trying to use youtube-dl on a Macbook (using Mojave). It used to work flawlessly but recently I am seeing the following error:

```
youtube-dl -x --audio-format mp3 https://youtu.be/somevidR4hhU
[youtube] somevidR4hhU: Downloading webpage
[youtube] somevidR4hhU: Downloading video info webpage
[youtube] somevidR4hhU: Downloading js player vflWnjS_n
[download] Destination: somevidR4hhU.webm
[download] 100% of 4.60MiB in 00:04
[ffmpeg] Destination: somevidR4hhU.mp3
ERROR: audio conversion failed: Unknown encoder 'libmp3lame'
```

I've tried to reinstall youtube-dl and lame with:

```
brew reinstall youtube-dl lame
```

but it makes no difference. Any idea what the problem may be?
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3):

Homebrew doesn't install the lame.  Compile with libmp3lame:

```bash
git clone https://git.ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg.git ffmpeg
cd ffmpeg
./configure --enable-libmp3lame
make
make install
ffmpeg -version
```

That should fix it

Comment: Having the same problem despite trying the above :(

Comment: `ERROR: libmp3lame >= 3.98.3 not found`

Answer (score 0):

The possible issue could be because of the broken symlink to ffmpeg. You could try below brew command if you have installed ffmpeg with brew.

```
brew link --overwrite ffmpeg
```

It fixed for me at least.

['libmp3lame'](http://lame.sourceforge.net/) is an encoder for mp3 which is getting used by ffmpeg to convert to mp3.

Comment: I am pretty sure its just ffmpeg issue,  you can try brew uninstalling ffmpeg and install again. Also check for correct symlink for correct path of ffmpeg after reinstalling.

Answer (score -1):

Installing ffmpeg with this command solved the problem for me:

`brew install --build-from-source ffmpeg`